# How to show $\text{tr}(aa^T A_1-bb^T A_2)\leq c_0 \text{tr}((a-b)(a-b)^T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $a, b\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}, A_1, A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, $ and $A_1, A_2$ symmetric,  if there exists a const $c_0$ s.t \begin{equation}\begin{pmatrix}A_1 &0 \\0& -A_2 \end{pmatrix}\leq c_0\begin{pmatrix}I& -I\\ -I& I\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}
How to show: $$\text{tr}(aa^T A_1-bb^T A_2)\leq c_0 \text{tr}((a-b)(a-b)^T) \quad (1)$$

From the condition, we only know \begin{equation}c_0\begin{pmatrix}I& -I\\ -I& I\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}A_1 &0 \\0& -A_2 \end{pmatrix}\end{equation}is semi positive definite,I don not know how to prove the relation with trace in (1). Can any help?

Comment: @user26857 It might have been unusual notation but the OP mentioned "trace" in the ending sentence so it's quite clear what "tri" meant. In any case, I have changed "tri" into "tr."

Comment: I'm puzzled by the close votes. Even in its original form, the question posed no confusion really (see the comment above). Now the question is clear, the OP has shown some thought on the problem, and an answer is already provided below. Just seems very unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it should be tr, thank you. @KimJongUn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll write $'$ for transposition. Let
$$
M=c_0\begin{pmatrix}I&-I\\-I&I\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}A_1&0\\0&-A_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then with $c=(a',b')'$, we have
$$
c'Mc\geq 0\iff c_0[a'a-2a'b+b'b]\geq a'A_1a-b'A_2b.\tag{$*$}
$$
It remains to recognize that ($*$) is the inequality you seek using elementary properties of trace:
$$
\text{tr}(aa'A_1-bb'A_2)=\text{tr}(aa'A_1)-\text{tr}(bb'A_2)=\text{tr}(a'A_1a)-\text{tr}(b'A_2b)=a'A_1a-b'A_2b,\\
\text{tr}[(a-b)(a-b)']=\text{tr}[(a-b)'(a-b)]=(a-b)'(a-b)=a'a-2a'b+b'b.
$$

Comment: Dp you think the LHS in formation $(*)$ should be $c'Mc\geq 0$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. I fixed it. Thanks.